# Prevent closing the Application if file not saved

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We have an application based on Eclipse-RCP. The problem I am trying to fix is as follows:
Say the user has an unsaved model file, and tries to close the application. The application rightly prompts the user for options to Save the file, Ignore it, or Cancel closing the application. Ignore and cancel are no-brainers. If the user decides to save the file, there is another dialog box that gives the user an option to either save the file or cancel the save (its a custom editor, similar to a Save-As dialog).

Now, the question:
How do I prevent killing the application when the user selects "Yes" in the first prompt, but cancels the save in the second? I thought of looking up the base class of the application, but couldn't find it. Or should I be looking at the custom-editor for the model file?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let a workbench part holding the model implement `org.eclipse.ui.ISaveablePart2` interface meant for cases like yours.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in RCP you have the luxury of returning false from WorkbenchAdvisor.preShutdown()

Comment: Thanks, but I dont think we subclass WorkbenchAdvisor. And I couldn't figure out a way to find which is the base for our application too.

Comment: Without subclassing WorkbenchAdvisor, how are you creating an RCP application?  In your Application.start() method, what are you passing in the PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench() as a parameter?

Comment: Sorry to drag this on, but I a RCP-rookie. I do see an Application class, but there is no start method. This is another thing I am trying to figure out, how are all the plugins tied up, but I guess that digressing from the original question. What else can I look at to figure out the class that is responsible for saving the editor in question? Thanks again.

Comment: @krnnd Search your project for "WorkbenchAdvisor". If you're working on an RCP app you definitely have a class that's extending it. Once you find it, override the preShutdown() method and put there any code you wish to be executed before your application shuts down.